# How to reset an UIGestureRecognizer?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I have a subview inside a view. That view has a PanGestureRecognizer.
I want user could zoom in inside the webview, pan around, zoom out, etc.
But I want that, when the user reaches left edge of the webview, the gesturesrecognizers inside the webView to be ignored, and only the PanGestureRecognizer from the view get called.

Well, I have accomplished this, by that code:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
float coordY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
float correctionOffsetRightSide = scrollView.contentSize.width-webView.bounds.size.width;

  if(scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 0)
  {
    [delegate viewOnlyRecognizeItsPan];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, coordY)];
  }

  else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= correctionOffsetRightSide)
  {
    [delegate viewOnlyRecognizeItsPan];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(correctionOffsetRightSide, coordY)];
  }
}



-(void)viewOnlyRecognizeItsPan
{
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [[[[arrayDeAbas objectAtIndex:currentViewTag] webView] scrollView] gestureRecognizers])
    {
        [gesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panRecognizer];
    }
}
```

"arrayDeAbas" is an mutableArray that stores webviews.

My problem is: after user touchs a button, I need to reset "gestures", so that it doesn't requires panRecognizer to fail anymore.
How could I could this?

EDITED:
Ok, I've founded a solution. Instead of using requireGestureRecognizerToFail:, I can simply setEnablle to YES or NO.

```
-(void)turnPanON
{
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [[[[arrayDeAbas objectAtIndex:currentViewTag] webView] scrollView] gestureRecognizers])
    {
        gesture.enabled = NO;
    }
}

-(void)turnPanOFF;
{
   for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [[[[arrayDeAbas objectAtIndex:currentViewTag] webView] scrollView] gestureRecognizers])
   {
    gesture.enabled = YES;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can remove it from view - [removeGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/removeGestureRecognizer:)

Comment: Did you mean remove the panRecognizer from the view, and them add it again? Or remove the gestures recognizers from the webview? I tried to remove the panRecognizer, but, when I add it again, nothing changes, the "requireGestureRecognizerToFail" keeps its relation between panRecognizer and the webview's recognizers.

Comment: never mind, I founded the solution. Edited above.

Comment: +1: I had just a similar problem, and your solution works fine. Thanks!